# Android Studio: How can take JSON file on the HTTPS page

Tags: android, json, androidhttpclient

I use this code to get XML or JSON from Internet but its just working on HTTP. So It's not working on HTTPS like Google api

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama
>
> Error 405!

```
private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
    String xml = null;
    try {      
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);          
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your code like this:
`

```
private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
String xml = null;
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //url request is get
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// return XML
return xml; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change request method to GET.